# Null check vs Optional isPresent check

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

Can someone explain how `Optional` helps us avoid `NullPointerException`?

```
Optional<String> op = someFunc()
if(op.isPresent()) {
   op.get();
}
String possibleNull = op.get();
```

Isn't this code prone to `NullPointerException` too? If so, then why is this code preferred over

```
String op = someFunc()
if(op != null) {
   op.get();
}
String possibleNull = op;
```

What possible benefit does `Optional` provide other than the fact that it helps us in knowing whether a function actually had a return value or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses for Optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional vs. null. What is the purpose of Optional in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746482/optional-vs-null-what-is-the-purpose-of-optional-in-java-8)

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can use `x.toString()` on an `Optional` that isn't present, but you can't use it on a `null`.  Also something like `x.equals(y)`.

Comment: I don't think avoiding exceptions is the big benefit [other than what I mentioned in my other comment].  If your code is broken, you won't get `NullPointerException` as often but you might get `NoSuchElementException`.  Big deal.  I think a bigger benefit is that if you use `Optional` consistently, so that a value can be present or `empty`, then when you get a `NullPointerException` you know that your code did something really wrong, like forgetting to initialize something.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Let's say you want to get a string returned by a function, convert it to upper case, and then print it out. If you have:

```
String someFunc() { ... }
```

You might be tempted to write:

```
System.out.println(someFunc().toUpperCase());
```

Of course, this throws `NullPointerException` if `someFunc` returns `null`. Instead, suppose we have this:

```
Optional<String> someFunc() { ... }
```

Then

```
System.out.println(someFunc().toUpperCase());
```

won't work, since `Optional` doesn't have a `toUpperCase` method. At this point -- hopefully -- you'll be confronted with an `Optional`, which should make you think about the case of the `Optional` being empty. This helps avoid NPEs, but probably only somewhat.

Now you might be focusing on how to get the value out of the `Optional`, and you might forget about the empty case. Ah, there's a `get` method:

```
System.out.println(someFunc().get().toUpperCase());
```

This brings back the same problem as NPE, except that the exception is `NoSuchElementException` instead. So if you blindly call `get` on an `Optional`, it really is pretty much the same thing as calling a method on a reference without checking whether it's null.

(For this reason, [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) considers `Optional.get` to be the biggest mistake in Java 8. See his interview with Angelika Langer [*JAX 2015 Fragen und Antworten zu Java 8*](https://jaxenter.de/fragen-und-antworten-zu-java-8-qa-33108) at about 16 minutes in. I'm not sure it's the biggest, but it is a mistake. People just don't expect `get` to throw an exception.)

If you're diligent about checking for null references or empty optionals, then

```
Optional<String> os = someFunc();
if (os.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(os.get().toUpperCase());
}
```

is hardly any better than the old

```
String s = someFunc();
if (s != null) {
    System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
}
```

The **real** advantage of `Optional` is that it's a library class that has a fairly rich API for dealing with the empty case in a safe way. It's often possible to process the value that might be contained within an `Optional` by chaining a couple method calls to the method that returned the `Optional` in the first place. For example, we could rewrite the sample above as follows:

```
someFunc().map(String::toUpperCase)
          .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String op = someFunc()
if(op != null) {
   op.trim();
}
```

When the interface someFunc() is invoked above, it doesn't explicitly say that a null value could be returned, so the caller is left to his/her own assumption.

By explicitly returning an Optional, the caller of someFunc() is made aware that the interface could potentially return null. From an interface creator's perspective, it lets him/her be specific about the return value rather than having to document it separately.

```
Optional<String> op = someFunc()
if(op.isPresent()) {
   op.get().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One scenario where Optional is helpful in avoiding NullPointerException is method chaining.

```
class A {
  private B b;
}
class B {
  private C c;
}
class C {
  private D d;
}
```

Let's say I have the above classes, and I want to make sure that an instance of class A has a non-null instance of D, but without causing a null pointer exception.
If I were to directly call `a.getB().getC().getD() != null`, then it might throw NullPointerException - say if `a.getB()` was null.

Of course, I can do

```
try { 
  a.getB().getC().getD(); 
  // do something
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {
  // handle exception
};
```

But that doesn't look nice. An elegant solution would be to wrap our objects in optional.

```
Optional.ofNullable(a).map(A::getB).map(B::getC).map(C::getD).isPresent()
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458451/check-chains-of-get-calls-for-null) for more.