# Optional.of(null)will throw NPE, I need to verify null before call the method?

Tags: java-8, option-type

Java 8 introduces Optional to deal with  NPE. In practical application，I can‘t understand a problem.

I have the method A

```
public void doSomethingA(String para) {
    Optional<String> name = Optional.of(para);
    if (name.isPresent()) {
        //do
    }
}
```

But if para = null, it will throw NPE.

method B

```
public void doSomethingB(String para) {
    if (para != null) {
        //do
    }
}
```

if I check para is not null, What's the difference between A and B.

Where is the meaning of Optional.

Comment: Use [Optional.ofNullable()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) instead

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) if you are unsure whether you have a value or not, but you do not want a `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

Use [`Optional.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) if you know you have a non-null-value or if it's ok for you if a `NullPointerException` is thrown otherwise.

Regarding the rest of your question: why `null` or `Optional` you may find the following question useful: [Optional vs. null. What is the purpose of Optional in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746482/optional-vs-null-what-is-the-purpose-of-optional-in-java-8)

Your question may also be related to: [Why use Optional.of over Optional.ofNullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696485/why-use-optional-of-over-optional-ofnullable)

Comment: if it's ok for a NullPointerException is thrown, Do I need to use it?

Comment: it depends on your use case. Most of the time I am dealing with values that I have no control of (they come from legacy systems, etc.) and then I use `ofNullable`. If I have control of the values, I rather prefer `of` as I want to see that `NullPointerException` if someone tries to deliver a `null`-value where I am certainly not expecting any.

Comment: Thank you for this.  But why the hell would you ever wrap a value in optional that you KNOW is non-null?  Is this just like a verbose way of forcing java to null-check something that should never be null?

Comment: Because of the cases where it might be absent due to a condition or something (try/catch? etc.)... I think the stream methods `findFirst` or `findAny` are good examples for it: if you filter a stream it could be that nothing matches... in that case `findFirst`/`findAny` would return an empty `Optional`, which I personally prefer instead of `null` (also due to the convenience methods that `Optional` offers)...

Answer (score 1):

Optional does not prevent from throwing an NPE, It  makes it very easy to avoid, but you have to do your part, for example, I would refactor your code to something like this.

```
     public void doSomethingA(String para) {
           
           Optional<String> optName = Optional.ofNullable(para);
        
           String name = optName.orElse("Unknown");
    //At his point, you are completely sure that name is even given name or "Unknown" 
    //and can do wherever you want without being afraid of throwing a NPE
    
        }
```

You can use other optional Method like:
`optName.orElseThrow()` to throw and error if your param is null,   `optName.orElseGet(() -> { return "Unknown" ;});`  practically does the same than the example but you can add more logic to get the default value, or many other methods.